# css gives 502 error on first time page load only

Tags: css, performance

css gives 502 error on first time only, I am using gulp in angular project. but on the same time if i open the css url manually in different tab, it open correctly.

Comment: How are you defining/including your css?

Comment: I am using gulp there, which combines all less files to one css file, and call this in index file. <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/app.css?v=1490012476549"/>

Comment: Are you directly accessing your website or you are going through some proxy?

Comment: directly accessing